# Thinkpad trackpoint scrolling with VMWare

Tags: vmware-workstation, thinkpad, trackpoint

ThinkPads have a middle mouse button for scrolling, sort of like a mousewheel.

The trouble is, when I'm using VMWare, the scroll messages don't seem to get through to the guest operating system and windows inside there don't scroll. It appears that the scroll message goes to the VMWare window itself.

In windowed mode, this is reasonable, but when the VM is full screen, I'd like to scroll windows inside it.

Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

I know this probably isn't what you want to hear, but from what I can tell there is no fix for this, just a lot of upset Thinkpad & VMWare users:

[VMWare Communities](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/30995)

[VMWare Communities 2](http://www.vmware.com/community/thread.jspa?messageID=176805&#176805)

I think the problem is that the VM Ware window is capturing the mouse event, and not doing anything with it. **A possible solution might be** if there is a driver for the trackpoint that you could download and install, you might be able to get it working in the guest OS.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows Host**: Are you using the latest drivers? [Check here](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-67941.html), for instance. VMWare scrolling support was added in 4.67. I'm sure the same is true of your current machine.

For a linux guest, you may still have trouble scrolling; I'm unsure.
But if that is the case, you may want to try:

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

- Locate *Configured Mouse* under the
  *InputDevice* section
- Change *Protocol* to `IMPS/2`
- Restart X

As for Linux as a host, I'm afraid I can't help.